# Cloud Firestore working fine with .get() but not with .onSnapshot() using next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm having some trouble that I'm not understanding very well playing with next.js and Firebase's Cloud Firestore, but basically this works:

```
export async function fetchBroadcasts() {
  const db = await loadDB();
  const firestore = db.firestore();
  const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
  firestore.settings(settings);

  return await firestore.collection('broadcasts').doc('message').get().then(doc => ({ broadcast: doc.data() }));
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
export async function fetchBroadcasts() {
  const db = await loadDB();
  const firestore = db.firestore();
  const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
  firestore.settings(settings);

  return await firestore.collection('broadcasts').doc('message').onSnapshot(doc => ({ broadcast: doc.data() }));
}
```

I can't figure out why the second option doesn't work since I'm basically following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

On my `index.js` page I have this:

```
static async getInitialProps() {
    return fetchBroadcasts();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`onSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onSnapshot) doesn't return a promise, so you can't `await` it.  As you can see from the linked API docs, it returns a function that you call when you want to stop the listener that you just added.

You use `onSnapshot` when you want to set up a persistent listener on a document that constantly receives changes to that document.  You use `get` when you want a single snapshot of that document.

Comment: yes, but how do I populate my props on `getInitialProps` using `onSnapshot` then?

Comment: Why do you need to use onSnapshot?  I'm suggesting that you shouldn't, if you just want to get data a single time.

Comment: I don't wanna get the data a single time, I want it to update it live.

Comment: Well, await isn't going to be the way to do it.  There are documentation and samples out there - start searching for that, then post here again when you run into a specific problem with your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore's onSnapshot() always return documents array regardless of query you use:

```
firestore.collection('broadcasts').doc('message')
    .onSnapshot(docs => {
        return docs[0].data();
    });
```

While in case of get you can get single document as well on the base of query:

```
firestore.collection('broadcasts').doc('message')
    .get( doc => ({ broadcast: doc.data() }) );
```